# Расположить элементы с рандомной шириной плиткой

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

Имеется контейнер с максимальной и минимальной шириной. Имеется рандомный список меток. Нужно красиво расположить метки в этом контейнере, чтобы оставалось как можно меньше пустого места, при этом верстка должна быть резиновой.

Порядок меток не важен. Название метки должно быть в 1 строку. Ширина меток фиксированная: 80px; 80px*2; 80px*3; 80px*4.
**Основной вопрос: можно ли решить  проблему с помощью CSS Grid или надо подключать JS?**

Код ниже демонстрирует проблему - создавая 10 меток рандомной длины из заданных размеров

```js
const container = document.querySelector("#app");

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  createItem();
}
function createItem() {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "item";
  const text = createText();
  div.innerText = text;
  const baseWidth = 79;
  const baseLength = 7;
  let width = baseWidth;
  if (text.length > baseLength && text.length < baseLength * 2) width *= 2;

  if (text.length >= baseLength * 2 && text.length < baseLength * 3) width *= 3;

  if (text.length >= baseLength * 3 && text.length <= baseLength * 4)
    width *= 4;
  div.style.width = width + "px";
  container.appendChild(div);
}

function createText() {
  const str = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
  const length = Math.floor(Math.random() * (str.length / 1.5 + 1)) + 3;
  return str.slice(0, length);
}
```

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#app{
  min-width: calc(90px * 3);
  max-width: calc(90px * 6);
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item{
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background-color: #F8FAFF;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0px 5px 12px 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
    <div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: попробуйте прописать свойство grid-template-flow: dense;

Comment: @Leks, мне бы подробнее

Comment: @ Дмытрык https://medium.com/@stasonmars/%D0%B2%D0%B5%CC%88%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-grid-%D0%B2-css-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-220508316f8b#2ccf заголовок явные и неявные гриды будет пример

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### можно ли решить проблему с помощью CSS?

да, можно.

```js
const container = document.querySelector("#app");
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const div = genItem(createText());
  container.appendChild(div);
}

function genItem(text) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "item";
  div.innerText = text;
  div.style.width = `${genWidth(text)}px`;
  return div;
}

function genWidth(text) {
  const baseWidth = 79;
  const baseLength = 7;
  let width = baseWidth;
  if (text.length > baseLength && text.length < baseLength * 2)
    width *= 2;
  if (text.length >= baseLength * 2 && text.length < baseLength * 3)
    width *= 3;
  if (text.length >= baseLength * 3 && text.length <= baseLength * 4)
    width *= 4;
  return width;
}

function createText() {
  const str = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
  const length = Math.floor(Math.random() * (str.length / 1.5 + 1)) + 3;
  return str.slice(0, length);
}
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="app" class="flex-container"></div>
```

по материалам:

- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp
- [https://medium.com/@stasonmars/всё-о-магии-отступов-в-css-flexbox-afaf6067a7f3](https://medium.com/@stasonmars/%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%CC%88-%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-css-flexbox-afaf6067a7f3)

  ```css
  .child {
      margin: auto;
  }
  ```

### так, по моему мнению, лучше

- https://css-tricks.com/flex-grow-is-weird/
  `flex-grow`

```js
const container = document.querySelector("#app");

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const div = genItem(createText());
  container.appendChild(div);
}

function genItem(text) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "item";
  div.innerText = text;
  return div;
}

function createText() {
  const str = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
  const length = Math.floor(Math.random() * (str.length / 1.5 + 1)) + 3;
  return str.slice(0, length);
}
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.flex-container>div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="app" class="flex-container"></div>
```

Comment: Благодарю, за внимание к вопросу, но Ваши решения не подходят: 1) слишком много пустого места в строках, в них могли бы поместится другие короткие метки 2) Не соблюдено условие по фиксированной ширине меток. Плюсик поставил

Comment: 2) первый пример - строго ваш код. 1) тогда только js массив строк и тд и тп

Answer (score 0):

Пока решил задачу с помощью JS

```js
const container = document.querySelector("#app");
const list = [];
const margin = 12;

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  createItem();
}
elemSort();
window.addEventListener("resize", elemSort);

function createItem() {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "item";
  const text = createText();
  div.innerText = text;
  div.style.width = getWidth(text.length) + "px";
  list.push(div);
  container.appendChild(div);
}

function elemSort() {
  const width = container.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  const arr = Array.from(container.children);
  let result = [];
  while (arr.length !== 0) {
    const row = createRow(arr, width);
    result.push(row);
  }
  setOrder(result.flat());
}

function setOrder(arr) {
  arr.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.style.order = index;
  });
}

function createRow(baseArr, baseWidth) {
  const result = [];
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < baseArr.length; i++) {
    const item = baseArr[i];
    const itemWidth = item.getBoundingClientRect().width + margin;
    if (sum + itemWidth < baseWidth) {
      sum += itemWidth;
      result.push(item);
      baseArr.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function getWidth(length) {
  const baseWidth = 78;
  const baseLength = 7;
  let width = baseWidth;
  if (length > baseLength && length < baseLength * 2) width = width * 2 + margin;
  if (length >= baseLength * 2 ) width = width * 4 + margin * 3;
  return width;
}
function createText() {
  const str = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
  const length = Math.floor(Math.random() * (str.length / 1.5 + 1)) + 3;
  return str.slice(0, length);
}
```

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#app{
  min-width: calc((78px * 4) + (12px * 4));
  max-width: calc(75px * 9);
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item{
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #F8FAFF;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0px 6px 12px 6px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 78px
}
```

```html
    <div id="app"></div>
```

Кстати, это можно было бы применить на этом сайте, в блоке "Отслеживаемые метки"

Comment: не вникал в ответ. предполагаю что происходит сортировка "тегов" _по длине_, вместо _сортировки по алфавиту_. в этом случае в угоду сомнительной компактности мы получаем нарушение логики и ожиданий пользователя. представим: у нас компонент содержит 100 тегов, нам нужен на букву __М__ 1) мы знаем что он где-то между __К__ и __П__ 2) мы ожидаем что теги __Java__ и __JavaScript__ находятся рядом ... . __Подводя итог__: либо так не делать, либо в обязательном порядке добавлять поиск и множественное выделение.

Comment: и тут мы возвращаемся к началу: а так ли компактна эта компактность.